# Return lambda capturing nonconst this in a const memberfunction

Tags: c++

In a pure const virtual member fuction, which is not intended to change the object, I want to return a lambda for later use. The lambda changes the object later, but this is outside the function and does not break the cv qualifier of the member function. How can I achieve this? Is const_cast a possibility?

Comment: Note doing this can cause undefined behavior if the object is defined `const`.

Comment: Don't do this. `vector` doesn't hand out mutable references in `operator[]() const`, even though it could.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `const_cast` in your lambda to cast the `this` to be mutable.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::function;
using std::ostream;

namespace abstract {
struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual auto get_remote_control() const -> function<void()> = 0;
};
} // abstract

namespace concrete {
struct Bar : abstract::Foo {
    int state = 0;
    auto get_remote_control() const -> function<void()> override;
};

static auto operator<<(ostream& out, Bar const& bar) -> ostream& {
    return out << bar.state;
};
} // concrete

int main() {
    concrete::Bar bar;
    abstract::Foo const& foo = bar;
    auto remote_control = foo.get_remote_control();
    cout << "Before, Bar{" << bar << "}\n";
    remote_control();
    cout << "After, Bar{" << bar << "}\n";
}

auto concrete::Bar::get_remote_control() const -> function<void()> {
    return [this]{ Bar& mut_self = *const_cast<Bar*>(this); ++mut_self.state; };
}
```

The caveats are:

- The Bar object actually has to be non-const.  If it is actually `const`, the subsequent `++mut_self.state` will be **undefined behavior** (thank you Caleth for the correction).  The **undefined behavior** may result in a hard to figure out bug.
- The returned lambda wrapped in a `function<void()>` object incurs a little overhead.
- The lambda holds onto a pointer.  If the Bar object is destructed, and then later the lambda is called, it will be called through a dangling pointer.  Which is also **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I read a lot that this is UB. Are there any caveats?

Comment: The `const_cast` isn't undefined behaviour, the `++mut_self.state` is.